# How do I add a code snippet to a sandcastle project?

Tags: sandcastle

I added a code snippet to a sandcastle project.
However, the code snippet does not show up in the resulting help file?
How do I specify that I want to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the XML Documentation Comments Guide:

<strike>http://www.dynicity.com/Products/XMLDocComments.aspx</strike>

It contains several examples on how to use the code tag.

HTH

**Edit:**
The MAML Guide is included in [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) and contains documentation on the code tag.

Also see [XML Documentation Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7) and [XMLDocsGuide](http://www.ewoodruff.us/Downloads/XMLDocsGuide.pdf).